# Cambiar el sonido de una notificación desde una url

Tags: android, android-studio

Muy buenas noches Amigos

me gustaria cambiar el sonido de una notificacion, he visto que la colocan en la carpeta raw/ y la llaman desde ahi. Pero a mi me gustaria llamar el sonido de mi notificacion desde una url. pero no encuentro la forma. yo estoy haciendo esto:

```
    private void createNotificacion(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logonegro);
    builder.setContentTitle(titulo);
    builder.setContentText("Mensaje Hariza");
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(detalle));
    builder.setColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    builder.setLights(Color.RED,1000,1000);
    builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000,1000,1000});
    //builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    builder.setContentInfo("EatBox Domicilio Zonal");
    builder.setSound(Uri.parse("https://hariza.com/Sonido/sound_app/baila_conmigo_.mp3"));
    //builder.setContentIntent(clicknoti());
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    Random random = new Random();
    int idNotify = random.nextInt(80000);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(idNotify,builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Es correcto como lo realizas, solo asegura que el mp3 en realidad exista, y revisa los puntos que señalo en mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Cargar un audio desde una url se puede realizar, convirtiendo la url a una `Uri` que es lo que estas realizando:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("https://--------------.mp3");
builder.setSound(myUri);
```

No debes tener ningun problema pero debes contemplar estos puntos.

1 La url del .mp3 debe existir.

2 Debes definir dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

3. Asegura que el dispositivo tenga activado el sonido para reproducir en el caso de notificaciones.

Comment: Muy buenas tardes Jorgesys, si tengo permiso de internet, pero sigue saliendo el sonido por default y no el de url, en url si existe por lo pruebo con Ctrl+B y me lleva a la url y suena el rington.. no tengo otra idea. Pregunto este sonido deberia sonar cuando llegue la notificacion? o cuando se abre?

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que me comentas, asegura que no definas en otro lugar setSound() únicamente debe estar el que agregar la uri de la url del mp3.